# Extract corner coordinates of polygon extent in PyQGIS / GDAL

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, geometry, ogr

My goal is to extract corner coordinates (i.e. UpperLeft, UpperRight, LowerRight, LowerLeft) from polygon extent using PyQGIS or GDAL.

In ArcPy there is a [handy property of an extent class](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/extent.htm) (i.e. feature['SHAPE@'].extent.upperLeft),
but is there something similar in PyQGIS / GDAL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PyQGIS you can use following code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    bbox = feat.geometry().boundingBox()
    xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = bbox.toRectF().getCoords()
    print xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
```

**Editing Note:**

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    bbox = feat.geometry().boundingBox()
    xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = bbox.toRectF().getCoords()
    print xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
    topLeft = (xmin, ymax)
    bottomRight = (xmax, ymin)

    print topLeft, bottomRight
```

[image]

Comment: It, works, thank you! But is there a way to directly get a proper X, Y pairs for these corners?

Comment: looks like QRectF has get bottomLeft() and topRight() which return a QPointF - see https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qrectf.html

Comment: @IanTurton I don't know if it is a bug but 'topLeft()' really produces a botton left point. So, it's preferable to group values produced with 'getCoords' method.

Comment: @xunilk so this way we could not get real corners of the source geometry, right?

Comment: Are you sure because that would be a hell of a bug

Comment: @IanTurton Please, see image in my **Editing Note** (point visualized with QuickWKT plugin).

Comment: @Basile Yes, you can. See my **Editing Note**.

Comment: I can't quite follow your code but I would check if the georeferencing of the layer is corrrect and that Y is really increasing upwards. If the origin for some reason happens to be at top-left then (xmin, ymax) would be at the bottom-left corner in the image. Make a test and see where (0,0) is placed.

Answer (score 2):

```
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open(fn)
ulx, width, xrot, uly, yrot, height  = ds.GetGeoTransform()
lrx = ulx + (ds.RasterXSize * width)
lry = uly + (ds.RasterYSize * height)
```

where:
`ulx` and `uly` are the upper left corner coordinates and `lrx` and `lry` are the lower right corner coordinates.

`GetGeoTransform()` returns a tuple with the following elements:

1. Origin x coordinate
2. Pixel width
3. x pixel rotation
4. Origin y coordinate
5. y pixel rotation
6. Pixel height