# Find raster pixel coordinates on shapefile polygon corners using Python

Tags: python, raster, polygon, pixel

I have a raster file and shapefile with multiple polygons.

How do I find **raster pixel coordinates** on shapefile polygon corners?

Not the geographical coordinates based on CRS, but the pixel row and column values on polygon corner location.

Later I will need to use these pixel coordinates to clip the raster image.

[image]

I tried something like this, but extracting all the px as points is not really a solution as it takes a lot of time.

And I don't believe that this is even the right way how to solve this.

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask
import geopandas as gpd


shapefile = gpd.read_file(r'W:\shape.shp')
geoms = shapefile.geometry.values
geometry = geoms[0] 

from shapely.geometry import mapping
geoms = [mapping(geoms[0])]

with rasterio.open(r'W:\raster.tif') as src:
     out_image, out_transform = mask(src, geoms, crop=True)
     
     
no_data=src.nodata
data = out_image[0,:,:]

for idx, row in shapefile[0:1].iterrows():
    row, col = np.where(data != no_data) 
    elev = np.extract(data != no_data, data)
    from rasterio import Affine # or from affine import Affine
    T1 = out_transform * Affine.translation(0.5, 0.5) # reference the pixel centre
    rc2xy = lambda r, c: (c, r) * T1  
    
    d = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'col':col,'row':row,'elev':elev})
    # coordinate transformation
    d['x'] = d.apply(lambda row: rc2xy(row.row,row.col)[0], axis=1)
    d['y'] = d.apply(lambda row: rc2xy(row.row,row.col)[1], axis=1)
    # geometry
    
    from shapely.geometry import Point
    d['geometry'] =d.apply(lambda row: Point(row['x'], row['y']), axis=1)
    d = d.set_crs('epsg:32635')

    point_with_polygons = gpd.sjoin(left_df=d, right_df=shapefile, how='inner')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after some digging I have found some solution with a help from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/409625/178904:

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import rasterio
import shapely
    
shapefile = gpd.read_file('your_shape.shp')
raster_path = 'your_shape.tif

    # This will give us a dataframe of pixel coordinates according to your shape file
    
def shapefile_to_annotations(shapefile, rgb):
    """
    Args:
        shapefile: Path to a shapefile on disk. If a label column is present, it will be used, else all labels are assumed to be "Tree"
        rgb: Path to the RGB image on disk
        Returns:
            results: a pandas dataframe
        """
        # Read shapefile
    gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)
    
    # get coordinates
    df = gdf.geometry.bounds
    
    # raster bounds
    with rasterio.open(rgb) as src:
        left, bottom, right, top = src.bounds
        resolution = src.res[0]
    
    # Transform project coordinates to image coordinates
    df["tile_xmin"] = (df.minx - left) / resolution
    df["tile_xmin"] = df["tile_xmin"].astype(int)
    
    df["tile_xmax"] = (df.maxx - left) / resolution
    df["tile_xmax"] = df["tile_xmax"].astype(int)
    
    # UTM is given from the top, but origin of an image is top left
    
    df["tile_ymax"] = (top - df.miny) / resolution
    df["tile_ymax"] = df["tile_ymax"].astype(int)
    
    df["tile_ymin"] = (top - df.maxy) / resolution
    df["tile_ymin"] = df["tile_ymin"].astype(int)
    
    # Add labels is they exist
    if "label" in gdf.columns:
        df["label"] = gdf["label"]
    else:
        df["label"] = "Tree"
    
    # add filename
    df["image_path"] = os.path.basename(rgb)
    
    # select columns
    result = df[[
        "image_path", "tile_xmin", "tile_ymin", "tile_xmax", "tile_ymax", "label"
        ]]
    result = result.rename(columns={
            "tile_xmin": "xmin",
            "tile_ymin": "ymin",
            "tile_xmax": "xmax",
            "tile_ymax": "ymax"
        })
    
    # ensure no zero area polygons due to rounding to pixel size
    result = result[~(result.xmin == result.xmax)]
    result = result[~(result.ymin == result.ymax)]
    
    return result
    
results=shapefile_to_annotations(shapefile, raster_path)
    
# print(result)
#   xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax
# 0 4023    5033    4288    5398
# 1 3966    4880    4331    5027
# 2 3146    4567    3398    4879
    
from osgeo import gdal
    
"""
Now, we can use 'results' pixel coordinates to clip some part of whole raster image
srcWin = [xmin, ymin, (xmax-xmin), (ymax-ymin)]
    
"""
    
out = 'out_raster.tif'
ds = gdal.Open(raster_path)
ds = gdal.Translate(out, ds, srcWin = [5000,4523, 3500, 1452])
ds = None
```

And the result with blue as an original raster image (`raster_path`) and green as clipped one (`ds`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this (i can not comment yet, thus as answer...):
[Extract corner coordinates of polygon extent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269748/extract-corner-coordinates-of-polygon-extent-in-pyqgis-gdal)

I had a similar issue earlier on and that solved it for me.

Comment: I'm not sure this solution gives me raster pixel index values for the polygon corners. I see that they simply extracting polygon bounding box coordinates and not raster pixel coordinates

Answer (score -1):

You can get the points coordinates of polygon and then extract raster values of these points. see this link [Extract corner coordinates of polygon extent in PyQGIS / GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269748/extract-corner-coordinates-of-polygon-extent-in-pyqgis-gdal)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).